# CSS center align ul list

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` list on my website that contains some sub menus. It is structured in this way:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>RNG</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>menu 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>menu 1</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>menu 1</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Altro</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>kldajofa</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Altro12</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have 4 `<li>` as you can see and I'd like to see them center-aligned with the width of the screen, but I don't know how to do it.

You can see a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neQbS/) here that contains the CSS too. How can center align the names I have on my menu?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are only 4 `li` - as in the example, set `width:25%`.

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTavj/)

```
#cssmenu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

[image]

I made a minor update so that the sub-nav menu items are also 25%..

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTavj/1/)

There were set to `width:225px;`.

```
#cssmenu li ul {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: This will affect sub menu items too

Comment: @AhmadAlfy That is the desired result though.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have only 4 menu items, you just need to add :

```
#cssmenu > ul > li { width:25%; }
```

This will set the width of the list items to 25%. And since the `a` are set to be displayed as blocks, they will fit the whole width of the `li`.

**Note** that we are using the direct child selector `>` because we don't want this effect to be applied to the menu `li`s inside the sub-menu. We only need that effect on the root level.

Other possible solution is to use [`flexbox`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which isn't well supported yet and cannot be used without polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

If the li are `display:inline-block` you can apply `text-align:center` to the `ul` and the list items will center regardless of the number (provided there is room on the line).

The good news is that there are no clearing issues.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/NwYbD/)

Answer (score -1):

I've just added width to li and it works now.

Check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neQbS/1/)

```
#cssmenu li a {
  background: #0D0D0D bottom right no-repeat;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
    width:70px;
}
```